# NodeJS: Redirect Client to Another Worker/Instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, websocket, instance

I got multiple instances of the same Nodejs application running on a website. I use websocket.

Let's say that the client is connected to the instance  #1. I want to transfer him to instance #2.

What I'm doing is that Instance #1 sends the data to Redis DB, then instance #2 gets it. But how do I redirect the client to the other instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `socket.io`,it can solve your problem

use `npm install socket.io` to install this package , and go to http://socket.io/ to learn document

Comment: I already use `socket.io`. How does this help me with redirecting websocket?

Comment: there is front-end and server-end in socket.io ,

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you cannot pass an open socket from one node process to another.

If you have a way to access a specific instance from outside (using a different port, ip or dns) you may either route socket connection at handshake (using http redirect) or after connection was established using a special event that the client will use to disconnect and reconnect to the other instance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to disconnect from #1 instance and connect with #2 instance. There is no way you can do soft hand-off though you might be able to emulate it in some manner by writing a wrapper on client side, which will disconnect from #1 and reconnect to #2. 
 If you use load balancer, just disconnect from client or server side (assuming you take #1 instance out of rotation) and have client re-connect.

Answer (score 0):

there is front-end and server-end in socket.io ,
between two end,you should regist events,in server-end ,you should regist client-event: emit server-event which regist in client-end ,and use broadcast.emit to send message to other instances,
also in client-end,you should regist the server-event:emit the client-event which have callback function

Comment: I guess we are not talking about the same type of instances. Broadcast.emit sends message to other clients, not to other instances. Nodejs instances are 2 copies of the website running at the same time physically separated.